# How can I get a CSS in Bootstrap that only applies within divs of a minimum column width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have centered paragraphs using "margin: 0 auto"

I want `h1, h2, h3 etc`. headings to start just a bit to the left of the paragraphs when there's lots of white space (such as within full-width divs on large screens). That's easy with margin-left settings. `Using @media` statements can exclude the margin-left for smaller screens.

*My problem is*: The `@media` doesn't remove the margin-left if, instead of smaller screens, the object is just inside a div that uses fewer columns. How do I make the object's margin not apply to smaller divs?

I want to do this without `JavaScript`. There's got to be a way to say, "*this* within divs of this many columns or more".

Would I have to write a rule that lists every single variation of div size within which to apply the rule?

Nice small screen:

[image: Nice small screen]

Nic wide screen:

[image: nice wide screen, centered]

Bad smaller div within a wide screen:

[image: bad wide-screen with col-md-6]

Those use:

```
    p { margin: 0.5em auto; padding: 0.4em 1em; max-width: 40em; }
    @media (min-width: 1200px)
        h1 { margin-left: 18%; }
```

The reason I want the paragraphs and headers centered in wide divs instead of just putting them in offset columns is because I want to be able to have full-width tables or images in the same divs along with the paragraphs. So all I really want is to to have that margin-left stop happening with smaller divs.

The best compromise I can come up with is just to center the headings, but I like the offset to the left a lot better.

Comment: I think some code here or a pictorial representation would be a lot helpful to understand your problem than describing in words.

Comment: You can also try with % values for the margin.

Comment: I edited the post for clarity. I'm already trying % value, and that's not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think it the other way. Let bootstrap do what it do for small screen and only use @media for  correcting `h1 ...` on big ones.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the problem. Without the @media, it is fine for small screens. So small screens are not the problem. The problem is the way the CSS that is good for wide divs on large screens works badly for smaller divs on large screens.

Basically, I want not "@media" but "@wide" so that a thin div does the same functional thing as small screens.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

It was a tad clunky, but better than writing out every single instance. The following code covers all cases (note: I'm using Yesod and it generates final CSS using the Cassius template and indentation — I didn't check if this case matches the final CSS or not, but the idea is clear):

```
    @media (min-width: 992px)
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 88px; }
        div[class*="col-"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 0; }
        div[class*="-12"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 88px; }
        div[class*="-11"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 48px; }

    @media (min-width: 1200px)
        a:only-child { white-space: nowrap; }
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 188px; }
        div[class*="col-"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 0; }
        div[class*="-12"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 188px; }
        div[class*="-11"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 138px; }
        div[class*="-10"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 88px; }
        div[class*="-9"]
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-left: 38px; }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually address non-column divs. I'm not sure we'll use them, but if we have headers and paragraphs within random other divs of various sizes or flexible sizes, then I guess I'll need to add rules for those cases.